# Pycups on python 3.10 and above Linux

Tags: python, ubuntu, cups, pycups

I have the following line of code in python:

`import cups`

When i run it i receive on the console:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cups'`

But when i try to install it with `pip install pycups==2.0.1`

i receive the error

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycups
  Running setup.py clean for pycups
Failed to build pycups
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycups, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've tried some things but can't figure out why this is happening. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.06LTS and Python 3.10.12. It worked on version 3.8 of Python but in this version it isn't working

i tried the command
`sudo apt-get install python3-cups` and it installed the version 1.9.73-3build1 but it isn't recognized as pycups

I also tried creating a virtual environment and installing it but fell into the same error

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Right now i'm using Python 3.10.12

First i download the project pycups on [github](https://github.com/OpenPrinting/pycups/tree/v2.0.1)

I installed the requirements while following the strunctions of the README

```
gcc
libcups2-dev
python3-dev
```

i also found out that before building i needed to run the commands on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.10-dev
```

then open the terminal in the file of pycups-2.0.1 and run:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

after that just run `pip install pycups` on your enviroment and it should install normaly